# Alternative layout for pretty printed JSON string structure?

Tags: php, json, string-formatting, pretty-print

I am interested in the means (any at all) to pretty print JSON to a layout format/structure that is not the standard.

I am asking this as I am producing barely readable, thousand-lines long JSON strings which indent several layers across long lists when pretty-printed in the standard format that every pretty printer uses.

So it would be very useful to semi-compact the output text from the standard, like this ---

```
{
  "currency":"USD",
  "total_profit":600,
  "float_money":500,
  "net_income":1200,
  "inventory":[
    {
      "dog food":100,
      "price":2
    },
    {
      "cat food":100,
      "price":3
    }
  ],
  "sold_stock":[
    {
      "dog food":100
    },
    {
      "cat food":100
    }
  ]
}
```

To something maybe a little more like this ---

```
{
    "currency":"USD",
    "total_profit":600,
    "float_money":500,
    "net_income":1200,
    "inventory":[
        { "dog food":100, "price":2 },
        { "cat food":100, "price":3 }
    ],
    "sold_stock":[
       { "dog food":100 },
       { "cat food":100 }
    ]
}
```

Any variation of the idea that is not fully compacting the JSON so it's still formatted and intended for human readability and consumption would be fantastic. It doesn't need to be like the above example specifically. I do envision perhaps a tool that accepts multiple parameters to define many alternative formats like where to indent or take a newline (like a code formatter in a text editor or IDE).

Even if it doesn't have lots of bells and whistles, any alternative format/layout/structure for pretty printing could be great.

Does anyone know of a utility, be that in an online or command line tool or some code that will help with this?

Comment: +1 for that, however, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Hmm. I really wanted to know the answer to this question, so edited it to try to make it meet the requirements. I guess my edit was not approved?

Comment: Anyway if the question was open, I have now come across an answer: Check out "NeatJSON". Available in ruby, javascript, and as an online tool: http://phrogz.net/JS/NeatJSON/